# Button pressed and two images xml android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button

I have two images. In one is a number, the other is shadow. I need to show this two images as can be seen in the second photo.

This is my code. Right now it only shows or the number (when is not pressed), or the shadow(when is pressed).

How is possible to show both images when the user press the button?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_select" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:alpha="0.75"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/number_1" android:state_enabled="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/number_1" android:state_pressed="false"
        />
</selector>
```

[this are the two images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAHAV.jpg)

[this is the goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52H9n.png)

Also I was trying using layerDrawable in this way, but didn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_select" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:alpha="0.75"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/number_1" android:state_enabled="true" />
</selector>

</item>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/number_1" android:state_pressed="false"
        />
</selector>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Please provide the images.

Comment: @AbhriyaRoy sorry, now yes

Answer (score 0):

You should use two different images...

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_image" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal_image" android:state_pressed="false"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: I know, thanks, but I need to show two images when is pressed, and one when is false, I upload the images with the model I need to follow.

Comment: How you want to display two images when button pressed?

Comment: You need to create one more drawable using layer-list. then it will work.

Comment: I dont know if is possible, but this is my goal : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI1oa.png

Comment: Refer to this link...

http://android-dev-examples.blogspot.in/2014/08/android-layer-list-drawable.html

Comment: @Nilash Patel could you show me how please? I don't know how

Comment: I dont know how to send images here. These are the images I upload. https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAHAV.jpg , and this is the goal : https://i.stack.imgur.com/52H9n.png ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use Relative Layout for that

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_select"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/number_1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just change image of iv_img  id **GOOD LUCK**

Comment: gosavi thanks, but I need to use it like a button, when user press must change the current image.

Comment: you can do it with this code  just change  android:id="@+id/iv_img"    image  

what ever you want and also set selector drawable to this image and android:id="@+id/iv_background"   is shadow is remain same for all

Answer (score 0):

please change the drawable selector file with this code..

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/number_1" />
        <item android:bottom="@dimen/margin_5" android:left="@dimen/margin_5" android:right="@dimen/margin_5" android:top="@dimen/margin_5">
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/button_select" />
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/number_1" android:state_pressed="false"/>
```

**Limitation ::**

It can use for single image of number ..for multiple numbers you have to create different selector.xml for each one..

Please tell if need more explanation or help..

Comment: thanks ! this do what I was looking for !! , just still is a small problem, when I press on button and shows the two images, the number becomes bigger than before, is posible to stay "number_1" with the same dimension was?

Comment: change the margin of this line to more as you need...
<item android:bottom="@dimen/margin_5" android:left="@dimen/margin_5" android:right="@dimen/margin_5" android:top="@dimen/margin_5">